# python regard a dict object as a _csv.reader

Tags: python, dictionary

i write a python program to convert a csv file to a list of my own class,here is the code

```
class node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cst_code = 0
        self.detail={};
    def setdata(self,CST_CODE,DATE,NUMBER):
        self.cst_code = CST_CODE
        self.detail[DATE]=NUMBER
    def add(self,DATE,NUMBER):
        if detail.get(DATE):
            self.detail[DATE]+=NUMBER
        else:
            self.detail[DATE]=NUMBER
    def sort(self):
        sorted(self.detail.items(),key = lambda e:e[0],reverse=True)
    def get_code(self):
        return self.cst_code
```

detail is a dict object,but python regard it as a _csv.reader

```
    ---> 16         if detail.get(DATE):
         17             self.detail[DATE]+=NUMBER
         18         else:

AttributeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'get'
```

did anyone meet the same question and get a solution?

Comment: Check if this works. "if seld.detail.get(DATE):" instead of "if detail.get(DATE):"

Comment: Could you provide the code that calls this class? For instance, what code produced that `AttributeError`

Comment: oh,i lost the self....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've probably created a variable named `detail` in an outer scope to that of method `node.add()`. Because you are referring to `detail`, and there is no object named `detail` in the method's scope, the outer scope will be checked for an object with that name. You might have an instance of a `csv.reader` defined outside of the method.

It would seem that your method should actually be referring to `self.detail`, not `detail`. To access the dictionary stored in the instance, not an outer scope:

```
def add(self,DATE,NUMBER):
    if self.detail.get(DATE):        # N.B. use self
        self.detail[DATE]+=NUMBER
    else:
        self.detail[DATE]=NUMBER
```

Note also that method `node.sort()` is missing a `return`.

Comment: get it!a careless problem